# Build an Octave struct by "rows"

Tags: struct, octave

I mean to use a struct to hold a "table":

```
% Sample data
% idx  idxstr  var1  var2  var3
%   1    i01    3.5  21.0   5
%  12    i12    6.5   1.0   3
```

The first row contains the field names.
I could enter these data by columns directly,

```
ds2 = struct( ...
    'idx', { 1, 12 }, ...
    'idxstr', { 'i01', 'i12' }, ...
    'var1', { 3.5, 6.5 }, ...
    'var2', { 21, 1 }, ...
    'var3', { 5, 3 } ...
);
```

and by rows indirectly, creating a cell array, and converting to struct,

```
ds3 = cell2struct( ...
  { 1, 'i01', 3.5, 21.0, 5; ...
    12, 'i12', 6.5, 1.0, 3 ...
  }, { 'idx', 'idxstr', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' }, 2 );
```

**Is there a direct way to enter data by rows?**

In addition,
**why the different sizes?**

```
>> size(ds2), size(ds3)
ans =

   1   2

ans =

   2   1
```

Comment: just do `ds3 = cell2struct( ...
  { 1, 'i01', 3.5, 21.0, 5; ...
    12, 'i12', 6.5, 1.0, 3 ...
  }, { 'idx', 'idxstr', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' }, 2 )';`

Comment: @AnderBiguri - I am not getting the difference between your proposal and what I posted.

Comment: the last apostrophe makes the size of ds3 the same as ds2. really not very important.

Comment: May I ask why you prefer to create arrays of structs? To me this is functionally equivalent to an array of tables all containing a single row, rather than a single table with multiple rows. I can see how that would be very cumbersome to work with...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - I have no specific preference. I simply did it this way, and I am certainly open to other options if they are advantageous.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in your other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124441/pick-a-struct-element-by-field-name-and-some-non-sequential-index), you are probably better off creating your 'table' as a struct of array fields, rather than an array of single-row structs.

However, for the sake of writing a useful answer, I will assume the reason you opted for this form to begin with may be that you already have your data as rows in 'cell' form (e.g. possibly the output of a `csv2cell` operation), and you'd like to convert it to such a "table".

Therefore, to create a nice "table as struct of arrays" from such a data structure, you could follow a strategy like the following:

```
Data = { 1, 'i01', 3.5, 21.0, 5;   12, 'i12', 6.5, 1.0, 3 };
d1 = struct( 'idx'   ,  [Data{:,1}] ,
             'idxstr', {{Data{:,2}}},   % note the 'enclosing' braces!
             'var1'  ,  [Data{:,3}] ,
             'var2'  ,  [Data{:,4}] ,
             'var3'  ,  [Data{:,5}]
           );
```

or, using `cell2struct` if you prefer that syntax:

```
d2 = cell2struct( { [Data{:,1}],
                    {Data{:,2}},   % note the lack of enclosing braces here!
                    [Data{:,3}],
                    [Data{:,4}],
                    [Data{:,5}] },
                  { 'idx', 'idxstr', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' },
                  2
                );
```

Note that you "do" need to know if a 'column' represents a numeric or string array, so that you wrap it in [] or {} respectively ... but I think knowing the data-type represented by each column is not an unreasonable requirement from a programmer.