# Pick a struct element by field name and some non-sequential index

Tags: struct, octave

I mean to use a struct to hold a "table":

```
% Sample data
% idx  idxstr  var1  var2  var3
%   1    i01    3.5  21.0   5
%  12    i12    6.5   1.0   3
```

The first row contains the field names.
Assume I created a struct

```
ds2 = struct( ...
    'idx', { 1, 12 }, ...
    'idxstr', { 'i01', 'i12' }, ...
    'var1', { 3.5, 6.5 }, ...
    'var2', { 21, 1 }, ...
    'var3', { 5, 3 } ...
);
```

**How can I retrieve the value for field `var2`, for the row corresponding to `idxstr` equal to `'i01'`?**

Notes:

1. I cannot ensure the length of `idxstr` elements will always be 3.
2. Ideally, I would have a method that also works for columns `var2` containing strings, or any other type of variable.

PS: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/35976320/2707864 can help.

Comment: This post reinforces my belief that what you were really after is a struct of arrays, rather than an array of structs. If you had the former, this would be trivial; now that you have the latter, you'll need to go through all sorts of hoops to achieve your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `idxstr` can be more than 3 characters (there is a shorter version of its always 3 chars), this is the thing I came up with (tested on MATLAB):

```
logical_index=~cellfun(@isempty,strfind({ds2(:).idxstr},'i01'))
```

you can access the variables as:

```
ds2(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind({ds2(:).idxstr},'i01'))).var2;
% using above variable
ds2(logical_index).var2;
```

You can understand now why MATLAB introduced tables hehe.

Comment: I confirm this works for me in Octave 5.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, I believe you have the wrong kind of struct for this work. Instead of an array of (effectively single-row) structs, you should instead have a single struct with 'array' fields. (numeric or cell, as appropriate).

E.g.

```
d = struct(
   'idx', [1, 12 ],
   'idxstr', {{'i01', 'i12'}},
   'var1', [3.5, 6.5],
   'var2', [21, 1],
   'var3', [5, 3]
);
```

With this structure, your problem becomes infinitely easier to deal with:

```
d.var2( strcmp( 'i01', d.idxstr ) )
% ans = 21
```

This is also far more comparable to R / pandas dataframes functionality (which are also effectively initialised via names and equally-sized arrays like this).

---

PS. Note carefully the syntax used for the 'idxstr' field: there is an 'outer' cell array with a single element, meaning you're only creating a single struct, rather than an array of structs. This single element happens to be a cell array of strings, where this cell array is of the same size (i.e. has the same number of 'rows') as the numeric arrays.

**UPDATE**

In response to the comment, adding 'rows' should be fairly straightforward. Here is one approach:

```
function S = addrow( S, R )
    FieldNames = fieldnames( S ).';   NumFields  = length( FieldNames );
    for i = 1 : NumFields,
        S.( FieldNames{i} ) = horzcat( S.( FieldNames{i} ), R{i} );
    end
end
```

Then you can simply do:

```
d = addrow( d, {5, 'i011', 2.7, 10, 11} );
```

Comment: This is also much more efficient in terms of memory storage.

Comment: I see the two advantageous points.
On the downside (and that is why I meant to organize my data the way I did), it is somewhat more difficult to add elements (equivalent to "rows") to my "table"; I would rarely add "columns".

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio this shouldn't be too much of a problem either. I have updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the code like below using `strcmp`

```
>> [ds2.var2](strcmp('i01',{ds2.idxstr}))
ans = 21
```

Comment: Concise! 
I confirm this works for me in Octave 5.1.0, even in the case of varying string length in the elements of `idxstr`.

Answer (score 1):

I put together function

```
function el = struct_pick(s, cdata, cnames, rname)
    % Pick an element from a struct by column and row name
    coldata = vertcat(s.(cdata));
    colnames = mat2cell(vertcat(s.(cnames)), ones(1, length(s)));
    % This assumes rname is a string
    flt = strcmp(colnames, rname);
    el = coldata(logical(flt));
endfunction
```

which is called with

```
% Pick an element by column and row name
cdata = 'var3';
cnames = 'idxstr';
rname = 'i01';
elem = struct_pick(ds2, cdata, cnames, rname);
```

and it seems to do the job.
I don't know if it is an unnecessarily contrived way of doing it.

Still have to deal with the possibility that the row names are not strings, as with

```
cnames = 'idx';
rname = 1;
```

**EDIT**: If the strings in `idxstr` are not all of the same length, this throws `error: vertcat: cat: dimension mismatch`.
The answer by Ander Biguri can handle this case.

Comment: Not contrived at all. These things are not easy to handle. I found that its much easier to have an struct of arrays than an array of structs. i.e. `ds2.var1=[ 3.5, 6.5 ]` etc. Makes all the extra things way easier.